# How to change laptop video contrast?

Tags: video, windows-11, graphics, hp, contrast

Windows 11 laptop HP 17t-cn300 newly bought. How do I change the contrast, hue, other advanced video settings? I am in Settings > Display, and it has night / red shift, brightness, but I do not see advanced settings such as contrast, hue. The brightness is on max, but I cannot see much on the screen due to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [HP 17t-cn300](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CC8S7KNR) uses ‎Intel Iris Xe Graphics. Paraphrasing [Intel's directions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058395/graphics.html):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *intel graph* and select *Intel Graphics Command Center*.
- Click *Display* in the menu.
- Select the *Color* tab.
- **Create a new profile** by clicking the *Custom* button. (The default profile is locked.)
- Adjust *Brightness*, *Color*, *Hue* and *Saturation* settings.

That said, I did not see a **Contrast** setting. Increasing *Saturation* might help a bit, and you might be able to increase *contrast* within an application. For example, [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) has add-ons such as [Font Contrast](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-contrast-fix/) and [Midnight Lizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/midnight-lizard-quantum/) to increase contrast and otherwise make text more legible.

BTW, Linux has a simple tool to control contrast: [xgamma](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xgamma.1.html). With a single argument, one can adjust gamma with a keyboard click. That would be nice in Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Settings (Start Settings), and in the Search box, enter Calibrate  Display color.

The colour calibration dialogue box will come up, and you can calibrate all colour and contrast settings . This is a complete Windows Solution for display calibration.

Tested here on Windows 11.

Works back as far as I can reasonably remember, but certainly Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11.

[image: Windows 11 Color Calibration]

Comment: Does this work for you @Kittensinurface   ?